# Apache Flink: stepwise execution

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Due to a performance measurement I want to execute my Scala program written for Flink stepwise, i.e.

```
execute first operator; materialize result;
execute second operator; materialize result;
...
```

and so on. The original code:

```
var filename = new String("<filename>")
var text = env.readTextFile(filename)
var counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map { (_, 1) }.groupBy(0).sum(1)
counts.writeAsText("file://result.txt", WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
env.execute()
```

So I want the execution of `var counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map { (_, 1) }.groupBy(0).sum(1)` to be stepwise.

Is calling `env.execute()` after every operator the right way to do it?

Or is writing to `/dev/null` after every operation, i.e. calling `counts.writeAsText("file:///home/username/dev/null", WriteMode.OVERWRITE)` and then calling `env.execute()` a better alternative? And does Flink actually have something like a `NullSink` for that purpose?

**edit:** I'm using the Flink Scala Shell on a cluster and setting the application with parallelism=1 for the execution of the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink uses pipelined data transfers by default to improve the performance of job execution. However, you can also force batch data transfer by calling

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ...
env.getConfig().setExecutionMode(ExecutionMode.BATCH_FORCED);
```

This will separate the execution of both operators (unless they are chained). You can get the execution time of each task from the log files or check the web dashboard. Note, this will not work for chained operators, i.e., operators that have the same parallelism and do not require a network shuffle. Also, you should be aware that using batched transfers increases the overall execution time of a program. I don't think it is possible to really separate the execution time of operators in a pipelined data processor.

Call `execute()` after each operator will not work because, Flink does not yet support caching of result in memory. So if you execute operator 2, you will either need to write the result of operator 1 to some persistent storage and read it again or execute operator 1 again.

Comment: I compare flink to a single threaded execution, so I'm always calling my application with parallelism=1. Is it then possible to separate the execution?

Comment: And does the single threaded execution have an effect on the operators chaining?

Comment: Chaining is an optimization that is always applied for DataSet (batch) programs. Chaining happens only if 1) both operators have the same parallelism, 2) the second operator does not require partitioning, 3) the first operator has only one successor. For example two map operators with the same parallelism will always be chained. Chaining basically means, that data is not serialized for transport but the resulting object is immediately forwarded into the next function.

Comment: So how is it in my application? To compute wordcount I use one map and then one reduce (consisting of groupBy and sum). But I still have three operators, right? And after the map a partitioning for the reduce is required. So it won't be chained after the map? But then my parallelism is 1 per default for all operators, right? Then chained? Not really getting it ...

Comment: For chaining, all conditions need to be fulfilled. So in your case, the Mapper and the Reducer won't be chained because Reduce requires a shuffle. However, Flink injects a Combiner which is chained to the mapper.